# Which process (kernel thread) is doing the actual compression for zswap?

Tags: linux-kernel, zswap

I can imagine actually two locations:

1. In the kernel space belonging to the process whose ram is being swapped in/out
2. From `[kswapd0]`

However, digging into the kswapd source (`mm/vmscan.c`, `init/main.c`), I could find: kswapd is single-threaded, and is started on a single thread. (Except on NUMA systems, where all the memory regions have a different kswapd. But most ordinary PCs are not NUMA systems.)

However, from now we have a problem. We can assume, that the disk is far slower than the memory, this is why we don't need a multi-threaded kswapd to handle the disk I/O. But not this is the case if we need to utilize also the internal zswap layer. Particularly from stronger compression rates (deflate), cpu can, and likely will be a bottleneck.

But kswapd is single-threaded.

Is it true?

Is being any multi-threaded kswapd planned? Is it really needed?

---

P.s. I found [this](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1522661062-39745-1-git-send-email-buddy.lumpkin@oracle.com/) thread on the linux kernel mailing list. It is about a rejected patch suggestion, what could have enabled multi-threaded kswapd on non-NUMA systems. They are talking about everything, except this zswap problem. Maybe it is unrelated.

P.s.2. Context:

1. I have a highly ram-overcommitted Linux system (processes are using far more ram than physically is available).
2. The count of the simultanously running processes is far lower than the CPU cores.
3. I am using intensively zswap.
4. In this environment, it would highly useful to use *all the available CPU cores for compress/decompress memory pages*. My current best estimation is that the page compression/decompression is being done by `[kswapd0]`, which is a single kernel thread. I am investigating the options to utilize all the CPU cores for compression/decompression. Essentially, it would be a way to transform the left-over CPU capacity to compensate the lack of the physical memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating a lot, I think I found the answer.

The actual compression is being done in the `[kswapd]`.

The writer of the rejection mail in the [cited thread](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1522661062-39745-1-git-send-email-buddy.lumpkin@oracle.com/) shows that the responsible person had at least some reason what he did not communicate, but more likely he simply did not know from zswap.

I installed the patch suggestion on my system. It makes `kswapd` multi-threaded, i.e. it can compress memory on all the CPU cores. The patch works like charm, and causes a significant improvement in zswap-ping environments.

The proof: I massively overloaded my system (qemu with large memory consumption + a pxz compressor), both its memory and cpu. After that, I see this in the `top`:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  927 root      20   0   12,3g   3,6g   3612 R 141,8  23,1  36006:53 qemu-system-x86
 5017 root      20   0 7607428   4,2g   1580 R  78,4  26,8   2:32.85 pxz
  354 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  53,6   0,0  32:17.28 kswapd0:5
  128 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  45,8   0,0  32:57.42 kswapd0:0
  352 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  40,5   0,0  32:16.80 kswapd0:3
  356 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  36,6   0,0  32:53.58 kswapd0:7
  350 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  35,3   0,0  31:15.53 kswapd0:1
  353 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  35,3   0,0  30:48.00 kswapd0:4
  351 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  28,1   0,0  31:57.45 kswapd0:2
  355 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  27,5   0,0  31:44.12 kswapd0:6
```

Yes, it also means the following:

- multi-threaded kswapd *hugely increases zswap performance*,
- it is not included in the mainline kernel,
- yes it is likely because incompetence or in the fear of instability.

---

The zswap parameters I've used in my test environment were the following (can be set up in `/sys/modules/zswap/parameters`):

```
same_filled_pages_enabled:Y
enabled:Y
max_pool_percent:50
compressor:deflate
zpool:z3fold
accept_threshold_percent:90
```

Comment: Can you share how I can install the patch?  Zswap has made my system slower and would be great to utilise all four cores.

Comment: @DaveC Just download it, apply into a kernel source and recompile the kernel. Although it was written for 4.*.*, it can be still applied, maybe with minimal changes, into a recent kernel, too. Would you like to see a gist from the patch? Btw, I extended my answer with the zswap configuration I used. Its default config is crap (for example, it does not use the best compression / page merge algorithm).

Comment: Thanks, what is the patch called? I only scanned the thread but couldn’t see a name/version?

Comment: @DaveC I can not remember, it was linked in the thread.